# When correcting for multiple comparisons, do you correct all p-values of all tests used from the same dataset?

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I have this pretty basic question, but I haven't found an answer. I have a dataset, and I've performed many statistical tests comparing various variables. Do I correct all p-values, regardless of the statistical tests used and the variables compared? Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what you’re trying to do. What is you goal in doing all of those statistical tests with your data? If you’re trying to find one reason that something is different from something else, remember the XKCD about jelly beans: https://xkcd.com/882/.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dave. I'll give you a concrete example. I have a data set of the time it took to react to certain events in two locations. I'm comparing, for instance, the time it took to react in the first location vs the second location, the time it took to react to one type of event vs another type of event, the proportion of events occurring in the first location vs the second location, and the list goes on.

In this sense, I'm doing these statistical tests with many goals in mind, the noteworthy one being exploring the variables that might affect reaction time. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It will help if you can say more about the data and what you want to get out of your exploration. With what you’ve said so far, I stand by what I just posted.

Comment: Hi @bagel, can you provide a bit more background into the data, how you calculate the p-value and what is the hypothesis you are testing?

Answer (score 0):

I’m making a bit of a guess at what you’re doing based on your comment, but it sounds like you want to hunt for a difference until you find one, and that’s a case where you not only control for the number of tests you do but also control for the number of tests you considered doing but didn’t do after you found the answer you wanted.

The reason to control for the number of tests that you would consider is to keep yourself from getting out of doing an adjustment for multiple comparisons of you happen to get lucky on the first test or two (or three, etc...).

This makes the most sense to me when you do tests like in post hoc ANOVA. Say there are five groups: A, B, C, D, and E. You want to find some evidence that not all are the same, so you keep testing them in pairs. AB is insignificant. AC is insignificant. Et cetera. But then BD winds up significant. You’re done, right? If B and D are different, then the five groups can’t be the same. And you even adjusted for the six comparisons.

No, you should adjust for all ten pairwise comparisons. It shouldn’t matter that you did the comparisons in some order. You planned to do all ten until you found an answer you liked.

So I’d say that you should be making some kind of adjustment for all of the comparisons.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for the insight. The way you put it, I'm indeed hunting for a difference between subsets of data within a bigger dataset. However, I'm not ending my hunt after I find one difference. I started my analysis with the goal to answer specific questions (does reaction time vary between locations? does reaction time vary between event types? do proportions of events vary between locations? etc.) If I'd found that one difference was significant, I'd have continued testing for other differences to answer my questions. In this case, would you suggest adjusting for all tests regardless?

Comment: There are a lot of subtleties in this. I’d suggest saying more about what exactly you want to find, or consult with a professional statistician to whom you can explain the problem after she signs something about proprietary information. (Certainly don’t post proprietary data!) Depending on the complexity, you may have to resort to using a statistician regardless.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think the problem is necessarily too complex to resolve here, so I'll have a go at it.

I have a dataset of reaction time to two types of events (A, B) in two different locations (C, D), with some events being preceded by an alarm. I conducted multiple Wilcoxon tests to assess if reaction time differed among types of events, locations, and presence of alarm. I also conducted Wilcoxon tests to assess if reaction time differed among event type in location C exclusively, and in location D exclusively. I used a Fisher test to compare proportions of events between locations.

Comment: I totally understand that there's a lot of subtleties in this, so if the information I offer you does not permit you to give an answer, I get it. In that case, I will consult a statistician for more help.

Still, even disregarding my problem at hand, I can't help but question the application of "correcting for multiple comparisons". Some people say it's best to correct all statistical tests used in a study, regardless of what tests were used and for what purpose. Others say you should only correct for multiple comparisons in the same "family" of tests. I'm guessing it's just case by case?

Comment: I think you could consider the proportion tests to be their own “family“ of tests, but for all of the tests involving reaction time, it sounds like you want to find something that affects the reaction time, so it would be best to do some kind of adjustment.